# Proving $\|a + b\|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\|a\|^2 - \|b\|^2$ for $a$, $b$ in $\Bbb{R}^d$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I have encountered the following inequality in the optimization article.

For all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the following inequality holds: $\|a + b\|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\|a\|^2 - \|b\|^2$.

The norm is a simple $l_2$-norm. This is all the information that was given.

It was written in the Appendix and was marked as "basic" inequality, without any sketch of proof or even naming. I have tried to prove it on my own or to find anything related to it, and failed.

Could you please explain to me how to prove it?

Comment: $\|a\|^2= \| (a+b) - b\|^2 \le (\|a+b\| + \|b\|)^2 \le 2\|a+b\|^2 + 2\|b\|^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).
\begin{align}
\|a\|^2 + \|a+2b\|^2
&= \|(a+b)-b\|^2 + \|(a+b)+b\|^2
\\
&= 2\|a+b\|^2 + 2\|b\|^2.
\end{align}
Dividing by $2$ and noting $\|a+2b\|^2\ge 0$ yields your equality.